# Socket stop all blocking calls

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, cross-platform

I am working on a networking library. I have already implemented Socket wrappers for both UDP and TCP connections. Now there are some situations in which after already creating the wrapper I need to directly work on the underlying sockets. But how do I stop blocking read() calls in the wrapper while not dropping the connection/missing any messages?

Here are some of the things I have thought about:

- Using DuplicateAndClose() which sounds like it does exactly what I want, preventing the first Socket instance from being used while providing me with a new one to work on and keeping the connection intact. But this seems to be a windows only solution.
- Setting the read timeout to 1 and checking for a `closed` flag everywhere the socket is used. I do not like this solution as it feels kind of hacky and would require quite a bit of code changes.

Are there any alternatives I have missed?

Edit: Switching to non-blocking or async sockets is currently not possible for me. But as pointed out in the comments with async Sockets this is easy to solve (for anyone else facing this issue)

Comment: How do you "receive" a socket. You need a reference to the socket self. You can read and write to a socket parallel. There is a way to set the socket to non-blocking, but I don't advise that, because it might drop the performance when not used correctly. I would go for async sockets. (BeginRead, EndRead) etc

Comment: with "retrieve" i was trying to say I stop the wrapper from using the socket (including stopping blocking calls) and use the socket outside of the wrapper. Sorry if that was not clear. I do understand that this is easier with async sockets, but I would like to keep the code I have already written for blocking sockets.

Comment: The only way is in windows.  Application register to receive port numbers.  So when a message is received at the network card then card driver looks up in a link list the first occurrence of the port number which gives the process number of the app that registered for the port and sends the message to the app. You need to put your app as first process for each port number. if you want to allow the another process to get message you have to forward the message through the link list to next process for the port number.